# RestKit: distinguish multiple requests in didLoadResponse:

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'd like to use RestKit and handle several different requests in the same class, i.e. in the `didLoadResponse:` method. How can I distinguish between the different requests? How do I know which request is finished?

I'm doing the request via

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient sharedClient];
[client get:@"/....", method] delegate:self];
```

Then, in the delegate-method

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    if (???) // request which gets XY returned
        ...
    else if (???) // request which gets YZ returned
        ...
}
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, the `RKClient get:` method returns a RKRequest object. Just set a userData to the request and retrieve it later in the delegate.

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient sharedClient];
RKRequest *request = [client get:@"/....", method] delegate:self];
[request setUserData:@"FirstRequest"];
```

and check it later in the delegate

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
    id userData = [request userData];
    if ([userData isEqual:@"FirstRequest"]) // request which gets XY returned
        ...
    else if (...) // request which gets YZ returned
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to your question, but I have the feeling that some people will come here wondering how to distinguish multiple requests in didLoadObjects, as I did. The solution is to use `isKindOfClass`.

For example, I make two HTTP calls when a user logs into my app, and I want to distinguish the object returned from the getUser call from the object returned by getSummary (because if I don't then it crashes). This code checks if the returned object is a "kind of" that particular class, and if so sets the object to a local instance of that object.

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {

    if ([[objects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[APIUser class]]) {

        APIUser *apiUser = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    else if ([[objects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[APIUserSummary class]]) {

        APIUserSummary *summary = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

    }
}
```